# comparing outputs from command.getoutput(cmd)

Tags: python

I have the following code that is working apart from one problem.  Im trying to compare the two outputs from commands.getoutput(cmd) but im getting syntax errors.  I understand that this is probably inherently wrong, but could someone point what im doing wrong

```
def DiffGenerator():

  try: sys.argv[1]
  except: print "No Directory to scan defined\n"

  try: sys.argv[2]
  except: print "No delay time defined\n"

  ScanDirectory = sys.argv[1]
  if not os.path.exists(ScanDirectory):
    print "Scan Directory does not exist :" + ScanDirectory 

  cmd = "ls -l " + ScanDirectory

  try:
    DiffFileA = commands.getoutput(cmd)
    print "Printing DiffFileA" + DiffFileA
    time.sleep(1)
    DiffFileB = commands.getoutput(cmd)
    if operator.ne(DiffFileA, DiffFileB)
      print "New File placed within " + ScanDirectory
  except:
    print "BLAH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider subprocess

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

```
subprocess.Popen(['ls','-a'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
results = subprocess.communicate()[0] #where [0] is the stdout and [1] is the stderr
```

EDIT:

Also can you please expand out your try except loops and use specific exceptions e.g.

Bad:

```
try: sys.argv[1]
except: print "No Directory to scan defined\n"
```

Good:

```
try:
    sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "No directory to scan defined\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `if operator.ne(DiffFileA, DiffFileB)` is missing a colon, which could explain a SyntaxError.  By the way, when reporting an error please copy and paste *exactly* the error message that you see.

But using if operator.ne(A,B):  is a very unpythonic way to write if A != B:, and I'd avoid it.

Comment: I am new to writing python so im sure u can understand why i come across things like this.  What would be a better way to to to A != B

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You can write "if A == B:" to test if A is equal to B, and you can write "if A != B:" to test if A is not equal to B.